# Failed to compile. HookWebpackError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: vercel, build-error, typegraphql

**Below is the error I'm facing when I deploy on Vercel. The build just works fine on local means when I do "yarn build" it's just run's fine but when I deploy on vercel it shows below error:**

---

Failed to compile.
HookWebpackError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
at makeWebpackError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:308185)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:105236
at eval (eval at create (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28771), :27:1)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:68649
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:444:143
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
at Object.TemplateLiteral (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:67573)
at async Object.BinaryExpression (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:59330)
at async Object.ArrayExpression (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:58890)
at async computePureStaticValue (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:21246)
at async Object.enter (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:27364)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78333)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78791)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78872)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78872)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78791)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
at Object.TemplateLiteral (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:67573)
at async Object.BinaryExpression (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:59330)
at async Object.ArrayExpression (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:58890)
at async computePureStaticValue (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:21246)
at async Object.enter (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:1:27364)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78333)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78791)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78872)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78872)
at async AsyncWalker.visit (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/index.js:6:78791)

Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

to solve this problem